# Which material is used in flex PCB circuits ?

Tags: flexible

We are planning to use flexible PCB circuit in our application. Can anyone please suggest the material used in flexible PCBs ? We are looking for the flex PCB material similar to the one used in Olympus Stylus camera. I am attaching the image for your reference.

[image]

we are looking for the material which does not break on bending sharply.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: you can just use standard software to design your board and order it as flex board; there's plenty of PCB manufacturers that offer that option. You don't have to concern yourself with the chemistry of the substrate.

Answer (score 1):

Flex PCBs almost always use some sort of [polyimide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyimide) as the substrate due to their flexibilty, strength, heat resistance, and chemical stability.

Comment: For full flex pcb's, indeed polyimide is often used. If something does not need to bend very often, in case of an encapsulated pcb. Sometimes just regular FR4 material is used:
"SEMI-FLEX is flex-to-install. Unlike polyimide, the FR4 core is not capable of continuous flexing. However it will bend a limited number of times (typically 5) at a controlled radius and to any angle." At my pcb manufacturer this is called SEMI-FLEX